# How do I...Store Image from imageview To sd card.on a button click

Tags: android

I was Developing an application which will have image on image view .

My need:

What i need is When i click the button then it should store the image that exist in the image view to the sd card(emulator).

Here is how i used:(but no expected results)

```
Button btnWriteSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWriteSDFile);
btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) myImage.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "image.png");
boolean success = false;

// Encode the file as a PNG image.
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {

outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);


outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
success = true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
if (success) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
});
```

In my above code i didnt get any error

It simply Shows  that "**save file in mnt/sd/image.png**" but no images found.

It would be appreciable if some one helps me to get me out from this rid.

**

> "Found out where the exact issues":  My program was running perfectly
>   @ 1st time if i click button and check in gallery means there is no
>   image but once i close and open the emulator then there is a image.But
>   i need to see the image as soon as updated how to do this any ideas?

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, but in order to write something to external storage, you should have the following permission declared in the manifest:

**android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Comment: Yup!!!!Thanks for Quick Response.But i have already added that permission in manifest.

Comment: How do you check whether the file has been stored on the device? Please check first with the **adb shell**, because in order to force file to appear in some Android application like Gallery you have to update the MediaStore.

Comment: Once again thanks for giving good information really its nice.  I checked in gallery only.Will update the media store and check.If it works then im glad of you help.

Comment: Hi well said as u suggested i updated the media store now it was giving the exact answer as i expected.Thanks alot friend

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to take a screenshot

```
private static Bitmap takeScreenShot()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

For saving

```
    private File saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) 
    {
        File snapShot=null;
        try 
        {
             ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
              File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
              f.createNewFile();
              FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
              fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
              fo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return snapShot;
    }
```

Need to give permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Hi Sorry i'm new to android after a research only statrd to develop this appa...I just have a doubt that is I have image in image view then why should i want to use screen shot..sorry if the que doesnt make sense

Answer (score 1):

if you use some thing like

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
myImage .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myImage .buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = myImage .getDrawingCache();

File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "image.png");
boolean success = false;

// Encode the file as a PNG image.
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {

outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);


outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
success = true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
if (success) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
});
```

and please set the following permission in androidManifest.xml

**android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Comment: This site is not for merging someone question and answers.

Comment: Hi i already did that.Gave permission in Android.mainfest but still didnt get the image

Comment: please see the uppermost code of my answer i have change something there.
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
myImage .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myImage .buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = myImage .getDrawingCache();

Comment: ok ok will give a try of your code and get back  to you with the result.thanks for your Response.